# Save SQL's JPA in String column on BD

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, jpql

I'm using JPA with Hibernate, on my project i have a UI with so much options from filter on SQL, it's like a Profile to search, the user choose options and choose a nickname from this Profile and save on BD.

But i think not a good idea map/entity Class just for a save filter, then i thought, why i don't save the JPQL/SQL on String column on BD, and retrive when user can use this?

I try use Criteria for it, but can't extract JPQL from this, how i can use criteria, or better for this issue?

A little example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Empresa> filtrados(FilterEmpresa filtro) {
    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Empresa.class);

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filtro.getCodigo())) {
        try {
            Long longCodigo = Long.parseLong(filtro.getCodigo());
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", longCodigo));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        }
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filtro.getNome())) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("nome", filtro.getNome(),
                MatchMode.START));
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filtro.getNomeResumido())) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("nomeResumido",
                filtro.getNomeResumido(), MatchMode.START));
    }

    return criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("nome")).list();
}
```

And FilterEmpresa.class:

```java
public class FilterEmpresa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String nomeResumido;

    public String getCodigo() {
       return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
       this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNomeResumido() {
       return nomeResumido;
    }

    public void setNomeResumido(String nomeResumido) {
        this.nomeResumido = nomeResumido;
    }

}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: so you say you're using JPA, but are simply unwrapping it and using Hibernate Criteria instead of JPA Criteria. Why?!

Comment: @NeilStockton I had a similar case in dev env, where we are having JPA 1.0 which does not provide the Criteria API which was implemented from JPA 2.0, so the best solution for me was to implement hibernate's Criteria.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to save a multi-criteria filter object in the database, but not as an entity? You won't be able to extract a JPQL query from a Criteria, since Criteria is transformed to SQL. And that would be an awful idea anyway. If you don't want to create an entity for it, save it as JSON or XML, but not as some String that you won't be able to evolve if the model changes.

Comment: @JBNizet, thaks for comment, i belive is a better pratice save the entity with user chooses on BD, and retrive it, i will try and post the result. Thank you.